# Make a div sticky to a SVG relative parent

Tags: css, svg, css-position, fixed, sticky

Let's say I have an ***SVG*** element

> SVGArea

And after it I have an ***img*** div containing an Icon

> IconImg

The structure is like :

```
  <div id="svgArea">
  <svg>
   #SOMETHING
  </svg>
  <div id="imgIcon">
    <img src={IconImg} >
    </img>
  </div>  
</div>
```

On click, the Icon image is placed somewhere in the SVG (according to computed w and y positions).

**The problem** : the Icon moves each time I scroll up or down or I zoom in/out. The  element doesn't seem to stay fixed or sticky. And I have trid all what I have found in internet :

```
#IconImg{top:0; position:sticky // or fixed}
#SVGArea{position : relative}
```

And there is no parent with ***hidden-flow*** attribute.

How can I fix that I have my Icon stay in place what ever the scrool or zoom ? Thank you for you thoughts and answers for help.

Comment: why not just have the image in the SVG itself?

Comment: Very good question ! Because in my SVGArea I have some complicated transformations applied on it and I don't want my Icon to have all this transformation I only need the Icon as it is.

Comment: By the way if you have a solution with the Icon as an SVG AND inside the SVGArea but without the overall transformation / style of the parent element it would be awesome ! I have choosed to put it in an <img> as a workarround for this problem : ))

Comment: Well without seeing the transformation it's impossible to tell. Please create a proper [mcve]

Comment: "h_ratio" and "top_diff" are some ratio values computed before.  

  svg.style('perspective-origin', '50% 0%');
    svg.style('transform-box', 'fill-box');
    svg.style('transform', 'perspective(30em) rotateX(33deg)');
    svg.style('transform', 'perspective(30em) rotateX(33deg) scale(' + h_ratio + ')');
    svg.style('transform', 'perspective(30em) rotateX(33deg) scale(' + h_ratio + ') translate(0%, -' + top_diff + '%)');

Comment: Please edit your question. [Try to create a runnable example using a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @RobertLongson Here is a concrete example in another stack over flow question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74290784/how-to-inverse-perspective-transformation-on-svg?noredirect=1#comment131207293_74290784