# How to inverse perspective Transformation on SVG

Tags: html, svg, inheritance, transform, perspective

Let's say I have a div in which there are two SVG elements : ***svgPlan*** and ***svgIcon*** (which is an SVG Image element).

**svgPlan**:

[image: SVG Plan]

**svgIcon**:

[image: SVG Icon]

A set of transformations (***perspective***, ***rotateX***, ***scale***, and ***translate***) are applied on the parent element **(*svgPlan*)** :

```
svg.style('transform', 'perspective(30em) rotateX(33deg) scale(1.7) translate(0%, -6%)');
```

**svgPlan after transformation**:

[image: SVG Plan after transformation]

I want to display the ***svgIcon*** inside the ***svgPlan***.

**THE PROBLEM :** the transformations are applied on both the parent element ***svgPlan*** and the child ***svgIcon***. It seems that the child is automaticlly inherting the styles applied on the parent and this is not what I want. I want the icon to appear whitout any effect.

[image: What I have]

**THE QUESTION :** How can I ***Disinherit*** my child element from father's style (which I beleive is not possible on SVG at the moment), or apply an ***Inverse Transformation*** to make the Icon appear without any perspective or style ?

[image: What I want]

**THE MINIMAL REPRODUCTIBLE EXAMPLE** :

```html
    <div>
      <svg id="svgPlan" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2118.5 624.2" enable-background="new 0 0 2118.5 624.2" xml:space="preserve"
    style="transform:perspective(30em) rotateX(30deg) scale(1.17)">
         <rect width="1200" height="400" style="fill:rgb(224,224,224);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
         <g id="svgIcon">
              <image x="550" y="120" width="120" height="120" xlink:href="https://svgshare.com/i/npz.svg">
              </image>
         </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not apply the transformations just to the rectangle element instead of the whole SVG?

Comment: @Sean The rect is just for the matter of example in my real case I have an SVG with couple paths, but anyways can you apply a perspective(30em) on an SVG rect ? I could not do that .

Comment: You should be able to. If not with CSS, then with native SVG transforms. And you can apply it to a group as well (`<g>`)

Comment: @Sean, Does it change something If you apply it only on rect ?

Comment: Are you able to change the SVG structure ? e.g. add a `g` element or move elements around?

Comment: Yes if it is a solution for making the icon straight on the plan I can figure out to add g element (or anything actually). Do you have a solution like this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer proposes solution that is not very related to SVG, instead it uses more general approach where perspective transforms from CSS are applied exclusively to HTML elements - some of those may be or may contain SVG images.

First some trivia:

- SVG has no third dimension ("z-axis"), so dimensional transforms or perspective are not possible there, [unless you do all the maths yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919398/perspective-transform-of-svg-paths-four-corner-distort). It hasn't even `z-index` and layers are just denoted by the source (DOM) order of appearance. SVG in its nature really is just a "flat" two dimensional vector graphic.
- SVG maps many of CSS style properties to its presentational attributes, but since in SVG there is no `rotate3d`, `translate3d`, `rotatex()` etc, they have no effect.
- CSS in HTML has those.
- In your snippet you are applying CSS transform to a HTML node that is by definition just a rectangle on a flat plane (like everything in the page).  That node in your case is a SVG element, but it could be a `<div>` with background image or just HTML `<img>` - in all cases those are just "viewport" rectangles showing (SVG) content within infinite (possibly transformed) plane.
- So you cannot "pop something out of it"; you can only manipulate "planes" constituted by HTML elements.

As I understand it, your use-case is to display marker icons like "sprites" that always face a camera above some tilted image (say a "map").  From your questions is not clear whether distant icons (those farther from the camera) should be smaller and overlapped by closer ones (what feels more natural, but contradicts that "un-inheriting" stance) or be same size each, with undefined overlapping strategy. Let's assume the former.

In "HTML" world you can nest transformed elements and let the children move with parent (with help of `transform-style: preserve-3d;`) to get them to desired place, and then apply negated transform(s) to their children to make those camera-facing again.

Let's start with baseline pure SVG flat image - "map" overview with two "markers" without transforms:

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox="0 0 800 400"
 stroke-width="10" stroke="black" fill="none">
 <g transform="translate(100 100)">
  <rect width="500" height="200" fill="silver"></rect>
  <path d="M 0 200 L 250 100 L 310 30 L 500 200" stroke="white"></path>
  <g transform="translate(250 100)">
   <circle r="20" fill="darkturquoise"></circle>
   <image width="80" height="100" transform="translate(-40 -100)" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-200 -200 400 516' stroke='black' stroke-width='20'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M187-14c-15-232-359-232-374 0l-1 23c0 131 77 244 188 297A329 329 0 0 0 187-14z'/%3E%3Ccircle fill='darkturquoise' r='127'/%3E%3Ctext font-size='150' text-anchor='middle' stroke='none' %3Ea%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E"
   ></image>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(310 30)">
   <circle r="20" fill="red"></circle>
   <image width="80" height="100" transform="translate(-40 -100)" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-200 -200 400 516' stroke='black' stroke-width='20'%3E%3Cpath fill='darkturquoise' d='M187-14c-15-232-359-232-374 0l-1 23c0 131 77 244 188 297A329 329 0 0 0 187-14z'/%3E%3Ccircle fill='red' r='127'/%3E%3Ctext font-size='150' text-anchor='middle' stroke='none' %3Eb%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E"
   ></image>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

(I've extracted image icons to simplified dataURIs and changed positioning to group transforms for better reusability and independence.)

[image]

Now let's introduce the slope and icon "sprites".

- SVG is now without icons and icons are separate `<img>`.
- Each `<img>` is positioned and transformed to corresponding location on the map. Custom properties here help with reusability, but static values could be hardcoded as well.
- Custom property `--slope` and `calc` also ease "automation" and allows alterations initiated from the range input.

```css
.scene {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 50px 10px;
 transform-origin: center center;
 transform-style: preserve-3d; /* this is important */
 --rotx-positive: calc( var(--slope, 30) * 1deg );
 --rotx-negative: calc( var(--rotx-positive) * -1 );
 transform:
  perspective(5em)
  /* slope: */
  rotateX(var(--rotx-positive));
}
img {
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(1px * var(--y));
 left: calc(1px * var(--x));
 transform:
  /* to have the bottom center peak touching the POI: */
  translate(-50%, -100%)
  /* negate the slope: */
  rotatex( var(--rotx-negative) );
 transform-origin: bottom center;
}
/*
 Unrelated hotfix: when the scene is tilted perpendicularly to camera (slope is 90° and) it is invisible, but *obstructs* whole viewport (or something), so there is no way to return back.
 Presumably because the camera happents to be "inside" it (?)  - its bottom edge is behind the camera.
*/
.scene {
 pointer-events: none; 
}
```

```html
Slope: 
<input type="range" value="30" min="0" max="90" value="0"
 oninput="s.style.setProperty('--slope', this.value);o.value=this.value">
 <output id="o">30</output>°.

<div class="scene" id="s">
 <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox="0 0 500 200"
  stroke-width="10" stroke="black" fill="none">
  <rect width="500" height="200" fill="silver"></rect>
  <path d="M 0 200 L 250 100 L 310 30 L 500 200" stroke="white"></path>
  <g transform="translate(250 100)">
   <circle r="20" fill="darkturquoise"></circle>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(310 30)">
   <circle r="20" fill="red"></circle>
  </g>
 </svg>
 <img style="--x: 250; --y: 100;" width="80" height="100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-200 -200 400 516' stroke='black' stroke-width='20'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M187-14c-15-232-359-232-374 0l-1 23c0 131 77 244 188 297A329 329 0 0 0 187-14z'/%3E%3Ccircle fill='darkturquoise' r='127'/%3E%3Ctext font-size='150' text-anchor='middle' stroke='none' %3Ea%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E">
 <img style="--x: 310; --y: 30;" width="80" height="100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-200 -200 400 516' stroke='black' stroke-width='20'%3E%3Cpath fill='darkturquoise' d='M187-14c-15-232-359-232-374 0l-1 23c0 131 77 244 188 297A329 329 0 0 0 187-14z'/%3E%3Ccircle fill='red' r='127'/%3E%3Ctext font-size='150' text-anchor='middle' stroke='none' %3Eb%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E">
</div>
```

Should render something like:
[image]

For single 3D transform this fits; for multiple simultaneous transforms either more maths should be involved or more nested wrappers for transformations.  See [example of nested transform layers producing sprite-like "dots" in 3d space](https://codepen.io/myf/pen/poyoyLr) in pen using this technique.

Comment: Nice answer, I wonder why using `position: fixed` in scene instead of `position: relative` that allow scrolling.

Comment: @mpromonet good point, no particular reason for fixed position, just habitually used in my doodling sandbox where I usually do not want scrollbars at all, and copied that here. Changed to relative as suggested, thanks for heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to achive that picture just by cancelling the `rotateX` to let the icon (which is put on the separate overlay svg) face to the `viewpoint` under the same perspective projection.

For example:

```html
<div>
  <svg id="svgPlan" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2118.5 624.2" enable-background="new 0 0 2118.5 624.2" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="position: absolute;  transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(30deg) scale(1.17) scaleZ(1.17);">
    <rect width="1200" height="400" style="fill:rgb(224,224,224);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    <rect width="610" height="160" y="240" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="svgIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 2118.5 624.2" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
    style="position: absolute; 
       transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(30deg) scale3d(1.17, 1.17, 1.17) 
          translate3d(calc(100% * 610 / 2118.5 - 50%), calc(100% * 240 / 624.2 - 50%), 0) 
          rotateX(-30deg) 
          translate3d(calc(-100% * 610 / 2118.5 + 50%), calc(-100% * 240 / 624.2 + 50%),0)">
      <image x="550" y="120" width="120" height="120" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZVZ0.png" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Scaling effect on the icon due to perspective projection is to remain though.

##### Brief explanations of transforms applied to the icon

- `perspective(30em) rotateX(30deg) scale3d(1.17, 1.17, 1.17)`
  : A copy of transform applied to `svgPlan`
- `translate3d(calc(100% * 610 / 2118.5 - 50%), calc(100% * 240 / 624.2 - 50%), 0)`
  : Translation from css transform-origin(50%, 50%) back to the original position(610,240)
- `rotateX(-30deg)`
  : Transform to cancel the rotation
- `translate3d(calc(-100% * 610 / 2118.5 + 50%), calc(-100% * 240 / 624.2 + 50%),0)`
  : Translation from the bottom-center of the icon(610, 240) to css transform-origin(50%, 50%)